# Position photo to the top of the screen

Tags: flutter

I have attached a photo below that I am trying to replicate.

With the screenshot below, I have a photo that I would like stuck to the top of the screen. I have tried a positioning widget, but nothing has seemed to work.

Any insight is appreciated.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Onboarding1',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        fontFamily: 'fonts/Avenir-Bold',
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
    );
  }
}

    class Onboarding1 extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            "assets/Onboarding1_Photo.png",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          )
        ]);
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Why dont u use Column widget or ListView, because there is no any stack in your image

Comment: @BosS Can you provide example?

Comment: @BosS I am using a Stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, you're setting the height of your image to fill the entire screen. Instead you can set it to fill a portion like this:

```
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
```

And I agree with @BosS in that you're not doing anything that requires a Stack widget. Here's an example using a simple Column.

```
class Onboarding1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.asset(
          "assets/Onboarding1_Photo.png",
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
        Column(
          children: [
            // smaller column with your text widgets
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I can help you, but have you tried this?

yourimage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;